# 'quote' is missing while sharing via Facebook Native app - iOS Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-ios-sdk-4.0

I'm working with Facebook sharing in my iOS app. 'quote' is missing while sharing via Facebook Native app, check the following screenshot:

[image]

---

But it is working fine when `FBSDKShareDialogMode` is `feedBrowser`. check the following screenshot:

[image]

What might be the issue? Is this feature is removed from Facebook recently?
Below is my code:

```
  let content = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
  content.contentURL = URL(string: "https://www.google.co.in/")
  content.hashtag = FBSDKHashtag(string: "#FeelingGood")
  content.quote = "Sample Quote"

  let dialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
  dialog.fromViewController = self

  dialog.shareContent = content
  dialog.delegate = self
  dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogMode.native
  if !dialog.canShow() {
    dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogMode.automatic
  }
  dialog.show()
```

I'm using **Xcode9.1**, **Swift 3.2**, **iOS 10.3.3** & **iOS 11**, and **FacebookSDK 4.19.0**

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? In the same situation at the moment.

Comment: No. It is the restriction from the Facebook, there is no official documentation though.

Comment: dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogMode.shareSheet , this work in my case

Answer (score 0):

```
  let content = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
  content.contentURL = URL(string: "https://www.google.co.in/")
  content.hashtag = FBSDKHashtag(string: "#FeelingGood")
  content.quote = "Sample Quote"

  let dialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
  dialog.fromViewController = self

  dialog.shareContent = content
  dialog.delegate = self
  dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogMode.shareSheet
  if !dialog.canShow() {
    dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogMode.automatic
  }
  dialog.show()`
```